# Как отключать readonly при клике на ссылку?

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте. Есть форма:

```css
.inp {
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post">
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="name" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить имя</a>
   </div>
  
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="familia" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить фамилию</a>
   </div>
  
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="login" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить логин</a>
   </div>
 </form>
```

Вопрос: Каким образом сделать что бы при клике по ссылке рядом с полем - поле становилось доступным для ввода текста?

Возможно вопрос примитивный, но я в JavaScript практически не разбираюсь.
Буду благодарен за любую полезную информацию!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var link = document.querySelectorAll('form a');
for (var i = 0; i < link.length; i++) {
    link[i].onclick = function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault;
        this.parentElement.querySelector('input').readOnly = false;
    }
}
```

```css
input:read-only {
    background: silver;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post">
    <div class="inp">
        <input type="text" name="name" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить имя </a>
    </div>

    <div class="inp">
        <input type="text" name="familia" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить фамилию</a>
    </div>

    <div class="inp">
        <input type="text" name="login" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить логин</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**P.S.** Добавил стили для демонстрации редактируемости.

**P.P.S.** Если поля в форму добавляются динамически, то лучше использовать делегирование событий — навешивать обработчик на форму и слушать клики по всем ссылкам.

Answer (score 0):

С использованием фич EcmaScript 6/2015:

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll("a");

Array.from(links).forEach(link => {
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
        link.previousElementSibling.removeAttribute("readonly");
  });
});
```

```html
<form action="?" method="post">
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="name" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить имя</a>
   </div>
  
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="familia" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить фамилию</a>
   </div>
  
  <div class="inp">
    <input type="text" name="login" readonly /> <a href="javascript:void(0);">изменить логин</a>
   </div>
 </form>
```